# Location for Add-in in Office 2013

Tags: ms-office, office-2010, office-addins, office-2013

I have migrated my project from Office 2010 to Office 2013. ( office plug-in with a DropDown Menu design).
Previously Office 2010 used to show Add-in options File->Add-in->"Custom Add-in"Menu.

What is the new position of Add-in, where does default add-ins go in Office 2013?

Thanks,
Pawan Kumar

Answer (score 0):

If it is any help according to ZDNet they are now called "Apps" instead of "Add-in's". There was a great article about this on ZDnet, here is a link:

[Microsoft Office 2013: Bye-bye add-ins, hello apps](http://www.zdnet.com/microsoft-office-2013-bye-bye-add-ins-hello-apps-7000002274/)

Here is the official Microsoft page about them:

[View, manage, and install add-ins in Office programs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/view-manage-and-install-add-ins-in-office-programs-HA010354315.aspx)

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Yes i have read zdnet articles but mine is COM add-in so it is different. It is not app nor VSTO Add-in.

I have tried porting my codeline to office 2013 from Office 2010 but can't find the Add-in anywhere whereas it is showing to be successfully registered and shown in Options-Add-ins.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help. My understanding is if the add-in is registered and active the add-in tab should appear on the toolbar. Maybe take a look in your code to see if something has changed in the API spec you might have over looked? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you have developed your add-in using VBA or VSTO.

In any case you need to enable the Developer tab (this is must for developing using VBA as the first step!). For this, right click on the ribbon and select **Customize the Ribbon** option. Check the check box for the Developer then click the **OK** button. Then under the **Developer** tab,

In case of VBA, you can see the add-in by clicking the **Add-Ins** button.

In case of VSTO, you need to click the **COM Add-Ins** button.

This works for both Office 2010 and Office 2013.